# Java Comparator removing values form String object

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, comparator

I am trying to sort List using java comparator  the reference is https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/net/java/dev/wadl/x2009/x02/ResourceDocument.Resource.html

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import net.java.dev.wadl.x2009.x02.ResourceDocument.Resource;
public class ResourceComparator implements Comparator<Resource>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Resource o1, Resource o2) {
        return o1.getPath().compareTo(o2.getPath());
    }   
}
```

But getting wrong values , the path has the below values

Before sorting:

```
/customer,/customer/{id},/order/{id},/order
```

After Sorting:

```
/customer,/customer/{id},/order,/order
```

I am not sure why "{id}" is missing after sort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. - ideally without resorting to an external type.

Comment: @JonSkeet when i write a program for other custom objects it works fine it doesn't work only for "ResourceDocument.Resource" object.